# No database connection

Tags: php, zend-framework2

what is wrong with my dbAdapter? I am going through this [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html), but I am not able to connect to the database server.

Here are some code fragments:

**Module.php**

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Acl\Model\Roles;
use Acl\Model\RolesTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

...

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Acl\Model\RolesTable' => function ($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('RolesTableGateway');
                    $table = new RolesTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'RolesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Roles());
                    return new TableGateway('acl_roles', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

**global.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=mycms;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
        )
    )
);
```

How you can see, I am working with TableGateway. If I make a dump, I can see the keys from exchangeArray() function, but no values. If I remove the whole, database connection in global.php, nothing changes.

The connection itself is correct, I can take the data and connect via mysql.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check error log in, you may find any tip about the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints. No error was logged and I created a new user in mysql with access from any host - nothing ...

I will setup a new skeleton and copy&paste the module "Album". May be there is a typo in my code.

Edit: I got it!
Here is my controller class before I found my error. The dump just gives some keys without the expecting values:

```
class AclController extends AbstractActionController
{

    protected $rolesTable;

    public function getAcl()
    {
        $roles = $this->getRolesTable()->fetchAll();
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($roles);
    }

    public function getRolesTable()
    {
        if (! $this->rolesTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->rolesTable = $sm->get('\Acl\Model\RolesTable');
        }
        return $this->rolesTable;
    }

    public function setRolesTable($rolesTable)
    {
        $this->rolesTable = $rolesTable;
    }
}
```

I added a foreach and can now dump or echo the results:

```
public function getAcl()
{
    $roles = $this->getRolesTable()->fetchAll();
    foreach($roles as $role) {
        echo $role->role_id;
        echo $role->role_name;
        echo $role->role_parent;
    }        
}
```

But, I don't understand, why I can't dump the whole object.